# Why docker directly communicate with internet not thorough localhost

Tags: docker, networking, ip, wireshark, packet

i thought that docker will communicate with internet via localhost
so if i capture the packet,
docker_ip -> local_ip -> internet_ip
it would be like this.

but wireshark result was different

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trp9I.png)

As you can see, docker only communicates with internet
and local only communicates with internet too.
how could it be?

Comment: sorry, 192~~ is local ip
and 172 is docker ip